# How do I grant permission for Huawei Launcher settings SDK 23+?

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, badge, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to access info about notification badges from Huawei Launcher Android 23+ (which requires runtime permissions).

I already have in my manifest these lines:

```
<uses-permission
android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission
android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

And yet I am getting this RuntimeException with the message:

```
Permission Denial: reading com.huawei.android.launcher.LauncherProvider
uri content://com.huawei.android.launcher.settings/badge/ from pid=16687, 
uid=10192 requires com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS, or grantUriPermission()
```

Requesting permissions using `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` immediately returns `"-1" == DENIED`.

Even trying to set permission through ADB doesn't help:

```
adb -d shell pm grant com.yandex.launcher com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS is not a changeable permission type
```

I've tried to grant the URI access through

```
context.grantUriPermission(context.getPackageName(), getBadgeContentUri(), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

or

```
context.grantUriPermission("com.huawei.android", getBadgeContentUri(), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

but that doesn't help either.

So what should I write in order to get proper permission to read: `content://com.huawei.android.launcher.settings/badge/`

Answer (score 0):

You need `<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE"/>` in the manifest.